# Why do i need both rulesets?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Take mod_rewrite for Apache server.
I don't fully understand why do I need both RewriteRules in this sample:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Originally found at this [DIY MVC](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/) tutorial, it seems like `^$` and `(.*)` mean the same thing. And why do I need two [L]ast flags since the second is not supposed to fire, right?
I'm trying to deeper understand all the internal mechanics instead of just copying the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `^$` and `.*` don't mean the same thing: the first matches only an empty input, the second will match anything -- *including* an empty input. The second rule should be enough.

As to why there is `[L]` here, consider an empty request, and no `[L]`:

- the first rule will turn the request into `public/`;
- the second one will then trigger, and turn `public/` into `public/public/`.

Comment: Thank you! What do you think is faster: ^(.*)$ or just (.*)

Comment: It is the same, both will match exactly the same thing. Don't bother with anchors there ;)